# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de insertar y validacion en SQLite Android? Insert ó insertOrThrow

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Insert te regresa un -1 el cual puedes hacer un

```
n=db.insert(valores x);
if(n == -1){
}else{
}
```

---

```
try{
n=db.insertOrThrow(Valores x);
}catch(SQLException e) {
Log.e(Errors.ERROR_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tanto [insert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) como [insertOrThrow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)), sirven para el mismo objetivo que es insertar un registro en la base de datos.

La única diferencia radica en que [insertOrThrow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) lanza una `SQLException`.

> ¿Cual es la mejor forma de insertar y validacion en SQLite Android?
>   Insert ó insertOrThrow

Depende de tu necesidad, tienes 2 opciones,

**quieres determinar por medio de la obtención de un valor -1 si ocurrio un error y no pudo insertar el registro:**

```
n=db.insert(valores x);
if(n == -1){
}else{
}
```

**o quieres lanzar una exception de tipo SQLException cuando ocurrio un error y no pudo insertar el registro:**

```
try{
n=db.insertOrThrow(Valores x);
}catch(SQLException e) {
Log.e(Errors.ERROR_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```